# Function pointer call results in InstrFetchProhibited (ESP32)

Tags: esp32

I have the following issue which I'm unable to resolve by myself. Perhaps one of you could point me to issues in my code which I don't see.

There is a class called *communicator* which handles an MQTT connection. I use `PubSubClient` as a MQTT client. The constructor of `communicator` looks like the following. Besides connection arguments, it also receives an array of structs `SubscriptionHandler`. These structs define which topics should be subscribed to and also point to a callback method. When a `communicator` receives a MQTT message, it compares the topic to the known ones and calls the appropriate callback.

```cpp
Communicator(char * mqttBrokerIP, uint16_t mqttBrokerPort, char *mqttUsername, char * mqttPassword, char * mqttClientHostname, SubscriptionHandler subscriptionHandlers[], int lenHandlers);
```

**SubscriptionHandler**. is defined like this:

```cpp
typedef void (*callback)();

struct SubscriptionHandler
{
    char *Topic;
    callback Callback;
};
```

I tried the following: In the main file, I defined two methods for demonstration purposes:

```cpp
void enableHandler()
{
  Serial.println("enable handler");
}

void disableHandler()
{
  Serial.println("disable handler");
}
```

The `communicator` is created in the `setup()`-Method:

```cpp
SubscriptionHandler handlers[] = {{&strEnable, enableHandler},
                                    {&strDisable, disableHandler}};
```

callback (in *communicator.h*) `typedef void (callback)();`

strings : `String strEnable = ("test/" + hostname + "/command/enable");` and the same for disable. Those are also defined in main.cpp –

As soon as the `communicator` receives a MQTT message, the ESP32 crashes with the following message:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x3ffc9306  PS      : 0x00060c30  A0      : 0x8017e97c  A1      : 0x3ffb1ed0
A2      : 0x3ffc9306  A3      : 0x3ffc9306  A4      : 0x3ffc9306  A5      : 0x3ffc1318
A6      : 0x3ffb1f44  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x800d4df0  A9      : 0x3ffb1eb0
A10     : 0x0000000d  A11     : 0x0000000b  A12     : 0x3ffc24a4  A13     : 0xa98b32f8
A14     : 0x3ffc1318  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000004  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000014
EXCVADDR: 0x3ffc9304  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff

Backtrace: 0x3ffc9306:0x3ffb1ed0 0x4017e979:0x3ffb1f00 0x400e280e:0x3ffb1f20 0x400d4f3e:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d5cff:0x3ffb1f90 0x400e4c45:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400889dd:0x3ffb1fd0
```

Therefore, something is wrong with how I use the function pointer (or somewhere which I don't even think about). Could anyone give me a hint where I could start?

Comment: What is `callback` defined as? And the `str...` variables - what are they?

Comment: **callback**  ``` typedef void (*callback)();```
*strings*** : ```String strEnable = ("test/" + hostname + "/command/enable");``` and the same for disable.
Those are also defined in main.cpp

Comment: And those strEnable a strDisable strings? If it's char array, you shouldn't have & here and for better readability it should be before function names.

Comment: You're passing the address of a String object to a char * pointer. That's very bad.

Comment: have you seen this? https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-mqtt-publish-subscribe-arduino-ide/

Comment: @Majenko, I was indeed unsure about this. But this mqtt lib uses this data type, therefore I thought about using it too. Is there a better way?

Comment: @jsotola, the thing is I'm subscribing to multiple topics and I want to call method x of class y when i receive something on topic z. Publishing&Subscribing works on the examples I tried before. But calling the function after receiving a message and determine which function to call crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. After moving `SubscriptionHandler handlers[] = ...` out of the `setup()-`method, the function calls work. Perhaps `handlers` gets overwritten after leaving the setupfunction scope. Could anyone validate my suspected reason?

Comment: Anything in local scope (defined in a function) is gone after the function ends. Even if you store a pointer to it somewhere. It's gone.